# Kendo UI MultiSelectBox update kendo.all.js to newest version

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, dojo, telerik

I found this JSFIddle a while ago that uses telerik kendoUI. `http://jsfiddle.net/bDvkQ/1038/`

In there is a Script "kendo.all.min" version: 2012.3.1114

I want to use a newer version of it (2016.3.1028) but when I try to use it I get an Error message: The Object doesn't support the type or method "get"

The Problem is that I also added a kendoUI Export to excel `http://dojo.telerik.com/` to my Project and it is trowing an Error that "kendo.ooxml.Workbook" is not a method if I use the 2012.2.1114 version.

Here are the JavaScript includes:

```
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/js/jquery.min‌​.js"></script> 
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/js/jszip.min.‌​js"></script> 
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/js/kendo.all.‌​min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/js/cultures/k‌​endo.culture.de-DE.m‌​in.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is simply that kendo has introduced enough changes that the original jsfiddle no longer works with newer versions of kendo(and excel export does not work with the older version).

See github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/680.

So you may need fix up the custom implementation to work with newer kendo(docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/widget-basics/…) or use one of the alternatives(actual MultiSelect widget with autoClose: false or Telerik's "recommended" way linked from the github)

FYI, the jsfiddle code still works in 2012.2.913: http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/uveTEb
But no longer works in the very next released version(2013.1.319): http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/EmASi

Comment: I am using "bootstrap-multiselect" now